# Sorting concatenated strings after grouping in Netezza

Tags: sql, xml, netezza

I'm using the code on this page to create concatenated list of strings on a group by aggregation basis.

https://dwgeek.com/netezza-group_concat-alternative-working-example.html/

I'm trying to get the concatenated string in sorted order, so that, for example, for `DB1` I'd get `data1,data2,data5,data9`

I tied modifying the original code to selecting from a pre-sorted table but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
select Col1 
 , count(*) as NUM_OF_ROWS 
 , trim(trailing ',' from SETNZ..replace(SETNZ..replace (SETNZ..XMLserialize(SETNZ..XMLagg(SETNZ..XMLElement('X',col2))), '<X>','' ),'</X>' ,',' )) AS NZ_CONCAT_STRING 
from 
 (select * from tbl_concat_demo order by 1,2) AS A
group by Col1 
order by 1;
```

Is there a way to sort the strings before they get aggregated?

BTW - I'm aware there is a GROUP_CONCAT UDF function for Netezza, but I won't have access to it.

Comment: Did you have a chance to test my suggested solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is notoriously difficult to accomplish in sql, since sorting is usually done while returning the data, and you want to do it in the ‘input’ set.

Try this:
1)
Create temp table X as select * from tbl_concat_demo Order by col2
Partition by (col1)

In your original code above: select from X instead of tbl_concat_demo

Let me know if it works ?